# Estimating regression coefficients in the presence of stochastic trend

Tags: r, regression, stochastic-processes

I have a very basic problem. My time series is modeled as:

$$
\begin{align}
Y_t &= a_t + \beta x_t + v_t \\
a_t &= a_{t-1} + w_t   
\end{align}
$$

where $ w_t$ ~ $N(0,W) $  with known $W$, and $v$ is white noise.

I don't know if I can use the usual linear regression here, since the values for $a$ are not deterministic and are not stationary. What method should I use to estimate $\beta$, and specifically, get $t$-statistics or $p$-values for it? Implementation wise, I use `lm()` for estimating my regression in R. I would appreciate it if you could mention how to do it in R.

Comment: Is there an additional error term in the model or is $a_t $ supposed to be the error term.  If $a_t $ is the error term you can use generalized least squares.  If there is an additional error term you can use a Kalman filter

Comment: @ZacharyBlumenfeld Thank you for noticing my error. I have edited the question. If I use Kalman Filter, it seems like I won't be able to compute t-statistics and p-values for the coefficients. Am I right?

Comment: If you estimate the model with a kalman filter and maximum likelihood you can get standards errors for $\beta$ and the variances of $v_t$ and $w_t$, so you can compute p-values for those coefficients.  It would not make sense in this context to compute p-values for $a_t$ since, as you said in your post, they are stochastic.

Comment: A similar problem occurs in neuroimaging, where the BOLD signal is modeled as a linear combination of regressors, plus an error term which is modeled as an AR(1) process plus white noise. There the approach is to first naively estimate $\beta$ using least squares, then estimating the properties of AR(1) + white noise from the residuals, and then applying a whitening filter to $Y_t$ and $x_t$ with the idea that the errors of the whitened data and regressors are now approximately white noise. Finally, the regression coefficients are estimated again. This is of course only an approximation.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious approach would be to use Kalman filtering with diffuse or partially diffuse initial conditions (e.g. $\beta$ diffuse) to estimate the coefficients and their variances.

If the sample sizes are not small, the estimate divided by the standard error should be approximately standard normal. [You could get there via CLT and Slutsky, for example, even if $v_t$ were not Gaussian.]